# How do I Cache External Scripts in my Chrome Extension?

Tags: reactjs, google-chrome, google-chrome-extension, popup, google-chrome-app

My popup index.html looks like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html
  <body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="https://www.sesamecall.com/build/app218.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

When people open the popup, they have to wait 2-5 seconds for the script to load. (My app.js is fat)

Is there any way we can cache it so the app loads instantly?

Is that even possible?

Comment: You need to fix HTTP headers for caching on that server. Note however, loading of external code will be disallowed soon on the web store, you'll have to include all the code in the extension's directory/package.

Comment: @wOxxOm Do you mind sending me the link about them disallowing external code?

Comment: I don't have it but it was announced multiple times and discussed all over the web.